# Error 400 valiting form "The request sent was syntactically incorrect"

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem trying to validate a form using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. The from just register an user with the given fields. I'm using a multipart form because the form also uploads a picture, but I already tried to use the form without it, but still the same problem.

BTW, I know there are many of this question but none of the anwers helped me...

If the form fields are correct, everything works fine. But if I enter an invalid field I get as response:

> HTTP Status 400 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

I simply want to show a bubble to warn about that field. Currently I'm using *"pattern"* in the html input tag, but user's can just remove it from the browser. I can invalidate the process checking in the controller and redirect to the same cleaned page, but that's just an uncomfortable workaround.

```
<form class="styleweb" id="registrationform" th:action="@{/site/new_user}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>

            <div class="styleweb">
                <label for="login">Login</label> <input id="login" type="text"
                    placeholder="Username" th:field="${user.login}" />
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('user.login')}" th:errors="*{user.login}">Incorrect stuff</p>
            </div>

            <div class="styleweb">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input id="password"
                    type="password" placeholder="Password" th:field="${user.password}"/>
            </div>

            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label> <input id="email"
                    type="email" placeholder="Email Address" th:field="${user.email}"/>
            </div>

            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="foo">Profile pic</label> <input type="file" name="profilePic" id="imgInp"/>
                <img id="profilepic" src="#" alt="avatar" />
            </div>

            <div class="styleweb">
                <button type="submit" class="styleweb">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

This is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="new_user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addUserPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());

        return "site/user/add_user";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "new_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processAddUserWeb(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user,
            @ModelAttribute(value = "profilePic") MultipartFile profilePic,
            BindingResult result) throws LoginNotAvailableException {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Form has errors");
            return "elovendo/user/add_user";
        } 
        else  {
            System.out.println("Form is ok");

            byte[] profilePicBytes = null;
            if (!profilePic.isEmpty()) try {
                profilePicBytes = profilePic.getBytes();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error converting to bytes image file");
            }

            userService.addUser(user, profilePicBytes);

            return "site/user/registered_successful";
        }
    }
```

And the User class is:

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Long userId;

    @NotNull(message="Login cannot be null")
    @Length(min = 2, max = 20, message="Invalid login lenght")
    @Pattern(regexp=Constant.loginPattern, message="Invalid login name")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 255)
    @Length(min = 8, max = 255)
    private String password;

    private String email;

    // constructor, getters and setters, ...

}
```

I also tried to use an implementation of [Validator](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/05/spring-form-validation.html):

```
public class FormValidator implements Validator {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return User.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        User user = (User) target;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "login", "required.login");

        // input string conatains numeric values only
        if (user != null) {
            pattern = Pattern.compile(Constant.loginPattern);
            matcher = pattern.matcher(user.getLogin());
            if (!matcher.matches()) {
                errors.rejectValue("login", "login.invalid");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and using it in the controller as (first there was no *@Valid* annotation, but with or without it does the same [same error] ):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "new_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processAddUserWeb(@ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user,
            @ModelAttribute(value = "profilePic") MultipartFile profilePic,
            BindingResult result) throws LoginNotAvailableException {
    FormValidator formValidator = new FormValidator();
    formValidator.validate(user, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("Form has errors");
        return "elovendo/user/add_user";
    }
}
```

but didn't work too. If don't use the *th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('user.login')}(...)* tag (it's dumb but I'm just trying desperatly to found a solution) returns:

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'login' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property
>   'login' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the
>   return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
>     (...).validator.FormValidator.validate(FormValidator.java:28)

Ask here it's the last stop before loose all my hair while dealing with this, hope somebody might help me.
thank you!

**EDIT**

Here is the log when I send the form post with invalid data:

```
2014-08-06 14:42:01.717 DEBUG 9759 --- s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /site/new_user
2014-08-06 14:42:01.718 DEBUG 9759 --- s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String es.sdfd.rest.web.UserWebController.processAddUserWeb(es.sfacut.model.user.User,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) throws es.sfacut.rest.controller.exception.LoginNotAvailableException,java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException]
2014-08-06 14:42:01.743 DEBUG 9759 --- .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String es.sfacut.rest.web.UserWebController.processAddUserWeb(es.sfacut.model.user.User,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) throws es.sfacut.rest.controller.exception.LoginNotAvailableException,java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'user' on field 'login': rejected value [u]; codes [Pattern.user.login,Pattern.login,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.login,login]; arguments []; default message [login],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@23d2602c,^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$]; default message [Invalid login name]
Field error in object 'user' on field 'login': rejected value [u]; codes [Length.user.login,Length.login,Length.java.lang.String,Length]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.login,login]; arguments []; default message [login],20,2]; default message [Invalid login lenght]
2014-08-06 14:42:01.744 DEBUG 9759 --- .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String es.sfacut.rest.web.UserWebController.processAddUserWeb(es.sfacut.model.user.User,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) throws es.sfacut.rest.controller.exception.LoginNotAvailableException,java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'user' on field 'login': rejected value [u]; codes [Pattern.user.login,Pattern.login,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.login,login]; arguments []; default message [login],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@23d2602c,^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$]; default message [Invalid login name]
Field error in object 'user' on field 'login': rejected value [u]; codes [Length.user.login,Length.login,Length.java.lang.String,Length]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.login,login]; arguments []; default message [login],20,2]; default message [Invalid login lenght]
2014-08-06 14:42:01.745 DEBUG 9759 --- .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String es.sfacut.rest.web.UserWebController.processAddUserWeb(es.sfacut.model.user.User,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) throws es.sfacut.rest.controller.exception.LoginNotAvailableException,java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'user' on field 'login': rejected value [u]; codes [Pattern.user.login,Pattern.login,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.login,login]; arguments []; default message [login],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@23d2602c,^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$]; default message [Invalid login name]
Field error in object 'user' on field 'login': rejected value [u]; codes [Length.user.login,Length.login,Length.java.lang.String,Length]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.login,login]; arguments []; default message [login],20,2]; default message [Invalid login lenght]
2014-08-06 14:42:01.745 DEBUG 9759 --- o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2014-08-06 14:42:01.746 DEBUG 9759 --- o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2014-08-06 14:42:01.748 DEBUG 9759 --- o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/error]
2014-08-06 14:42:01.749 DEBUG 9759 --- s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2014-08-06 14:42:01.749 DEBUG 9759 --- s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String es.sfacut.rest.controller.MainController.errorPage()]
2014-08-06 14:42:01.751 DEBUG 9759 --- o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@503dc0cf] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-08-06 14:42:01.755 DEBUG 9759 --- o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

And this is the log with valid data:

```
2014-08-06 14:54:25.703 DEBUG 10138 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/site/new_user]
2014-08-06 14:54:25.703 DEBUG 10138 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /site/new_user
2014-08-06 14:54:25.705 DEBUG 10138 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String es.sfacut.rest.web.UserWebController.addUserPage(org.springframework.ui.Model)]
2014-08-06 14:54:25.705 DEBUG 10138 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/site/new_user] is: -1
2014-08-06 14:54:25.712 DEBUG 10138 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@4b34f94d] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-08-06 14:54:25.722 DEBUG 10138 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Have you tried placing `BindingResult` right after `User user` (you now have it after `MultipartFile profilePic`)?

Comment: @geoand Ok, now I get the expected page instead the error page, but I see no error messages at all at form fields. With or without using my Validator's implementation.

Comment: Try adding `@Valid` in front of `@ModelAttribute` and let me know what happens

Comment: Sorry @geoand, you were right with your first response! It was my fault because I had commented the <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors(...) tag, so that's why I was receiving any errors. So I have to expect that BindingResult has to be ALWAYS after the validation objects? I never found any reference to that, that's why I put it and the end, just for ordering stuff.

Comment: I remember bumping into similar issues before, and the solution was  the positioning of the BindingResult. I will try and find some documentation on it. Meanwhile I added an answer for future viewers to quickly find without having to read the comments

Comment: I couldn't find any official reference on the positioning of `BindingResult`. I would have to go through the source code to get an answer, but unfortunately I can't easily do that on my current machine :)

Comment: Nevermind, I found it: _The Errors or BindingResult parameters have to follow the model object that is being bound immediately as the method signature might have more that one model object and Spring will create a separate BindingResult instance for each of them so the following sample won't work_ http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html at 16.3.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to place `BindingResult` right after `User user` for Spring to able to handle the invalid data correctly.

The controller method would thus look like:

```
public String processAddUserWeb(@ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user,
                                BindingResult result,
                                @ModelAttribute(value = "profilePic") MultipartFile profilePic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of your `<input>` elements

```
<input id="login" type="text" placeholder="Username" th:field="${user.login}" />
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" th:field="${user.password}"/>
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" th:field="${user.email}"/>
```

don't have a `name` attribute. The `name` attribute is required for the `<input>` element to be sent as part of the submitted `<form>`. So these aren't being sent and validation seems to fail.

Add a `name` attribute, probably with the same value as `id`, to your `<input>` elements.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but adding the name attribute makes no difference at all. I tried several things with the attribute added but nothings seems to work.

Comment: @frostering Are you sending valid data? Turn your logs to DEBUG level and show us exactly what gets printed for a bad request and for a good request.

Comment: When i send valid data and everything works fine. But not if data is invalid. I've made a workround using HTML5 pattern attribute and throwing an error page if the Html5 form has been edited (so I don't allow invalid values), but I wonder how and why this isn't working. I guess Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling has something to do with?

Answer (score 0):

Invalid ordering of BindingResult and @ModelAttribute
I just change the order and woking like a charm...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser( @ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")@Valid User user,BindingResult binding, ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println(binding.toString());

    if (!binding.hasErrors()) {

        System.out.println("Has No Error");
        model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("password", user.getPassword());
        model.addAttribute("address", user.getAddress());
        model.addAttribute("receivePaper", user.isReceivePaper());
        model.addAttribute("favoriteFrameworks", user.getFavoriteFrameworks());
        model.addAttribute("gender", user.getGender());
        model.addAttribute("favoriteNumber", user.getFavoriteNumber());
        model.addAttribute("country", user.getCountry());

        return "users";

    } else {
        System.out.println("Has  Error");

        return "error";
    }

}
```